# FOSRestBundle can't get param fetcher

Tags: php, rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm trying to make my controller work with param fetcher. I did all instructions specified in the documentation. So what I have:
config
fos_rest.yml:

```
fos_rest:
  param_fetcher_listener: 'force'
  view:
      formats:
          json: true
          xml: false
          rss: false
      mime_types:
          json: ['application/json', 'application/x-json', 'application/vnd.example-com.foo+json']
          png: 'image/png'
      failed_validation: HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
      default_engine: twig
      view_response_listener: 'force'
  format_listener:
      default_priorities:
          - json
  routing_loader:
      default_format: json
```

sensio_framework_extra:
      view:    { annotations: false }
      router:  { annotations: true }

And my controller

```
<?php

namespace Push\PointsBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\Annotation\ApiDoc;
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\QueryParam;
use FOS\RestBundle\Request\ParamFetcherInterface;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\RequestParam;
use FOS\RestBundle\Request\ParamFetcher;

class RestController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @QueryParam(name="latitude", requirements="[0-9.]+", default="0", description="")
     * @ApiDoc()
     */
    public function checkPointsAction(ParamFetcher $params)
    {
        $view = new View();
        return $this->get('fos_rest.view_handler')->handle($view);
    }
}
```

When I calls method I get:

> Controller
>   "Push\PointsBundle\Controller\RestController::checkPointsAction()"
>   requires that you provide a value for the "$params" argument (because
>   there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument
>   after this one).

What I did wrong or missed something? Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I often have problems with FOSRestBundle and outdated cache. It simply doesn't refresh sometimes if I make a change in annotations. First, try removing contents of your app/cache directory (rm -rf app/cache/*).

I didn't check if parameters are mapped to method arguments by a type or a name. If it's the later than your parameter should be called `$paramFetcher` (not `$params`):

```
public function checkPointsAction(ParamFetcher $paramFetcher) { }
```

Edit: have you enabled param fetcher listener?

```
fos_rest:
    param_fetcher_listener: true
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I tried to clear the cache and tried to rename argument, but it didn't help at all :(

Comment: I looked at logs and noticed that symfony notified only BodyListener. There is no entries about PararmFetcherListener

Comment: Have you enabled param fetcher listener? I updated my answer with proper config.

Comment: Ofcourse, I posted my config too. And I enabled it even with force option and tried with true option too. There is no difference for my case, still got error

Comment: I forgot to include config file in config.yml and yes param should be exact ParamFetcher $paramFetcher

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, as pointed out in the comment. I solved this by changing the Variable name from

```
  public function addMapAction(ParamFetcher $pf) {
```

to

```
  public function addMapAction(ParamFetcher $paramFetcher) {
```

And all the sudden i worked like a charm, apparently $paramFetcher is required.

Comment: I was pulling my hair out trying to get QueryParam working... This did it for me.